# recyclerview on fragment gets a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement recyclerview on fragment but the app keeps on crashing with this log:

```
                                                                       Process: com.example.jovie.canteen, PID: 25378
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.jovie.canteen.OneFragment.onViewCreated(OneFragment.java:58)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But the log points this line:

```
at com.example.jovie.canteen.OneFragment.onViewCreated(OneFragment.java:58)
```

at: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);`

But I don't have any idea how can I fix it:/

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {


public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(generatePalettes()));

}


private ArrayList<Palette> generatePalettes() {
    ArrayList<Palette> palettes = new ArrayList<>();
    palettes.add(new Palette("We bring you closer to the real world", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    palettes.add(new Palette("", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    palettes.add(new Palette("", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    palettes.add(new Palette("", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    palettes.add(new Palette("", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    palettes.add(new Palette("", "", Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    return palettes;

}
```

Comment: check `fragment_one.xml` if id `recyclerList` exist

Comment: You're right, so I placed my recyclerList on my fragment_one.xml which it was on my content_main.xml before, sorry and thanks!